# SQL Decimal Format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, decimal, taskscheduler

I am using a basic console app with windows task scheduler.

The program takes some decimal value from the net and saves in the SQL Server table.

When I run the program manually there is no problem with the decimal format.

If task scheduler runs the program it reads them (i am guessing here) as int.

Example:

- while I run the program: 3.7658 => 3.7658
- Windows Task Scheduler: 3.7654 => 37658

I tried converting it to string replacing "," with ".".

```
decimal valueKur = 0;

valueKur = Convert.ToDecimal(xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("Tarih_Date/Currency[@Kod='{0}']/BanknoteSelling", item)).InnerXml);

mevcutKur.KurValue = valueKur;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should provide the code

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: Make sure you are running with the same executable.  In VS you may be using the debug version and the scheduler is using the release version.  Check in the bin folder that the debug and release version were built at the same time.

Comment: I edited my question you may find the code above

Comment: you need to show more code. What type is mevcutKur.KurValue ??

Comment: @GuidoG, it is deceimal type in code and in sql it is money.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you've used string concatenation to update the data in the database. Basically: don't ever do that. If you use a SQL *parameter* (`SET whatever=@whatever`, etc), then the database won't *need* to do any string parsing, and there will be no confusion - especially over i18n/l10n issue like whether comma/period is a group separator or decimal point. Likewise, store it *as* a decimal type in the database (not a string/char/etc type), read it out as a decimal type, etc.

When you treat things as text, everything is dependent on your *locale* - and the locale of the scheduler is not necessrily the locale you had in mind.

Comment: If i wasn't clear i am sorry about that. I already tried without converting to string. I am using entity framework. So there is no sql parameters

Comment: @Battlelamb EF isn't going to get confused about this, as long as the SQL column is actually a decimal type; you're going to need to show some code at some point - somewhere perhaps in parsing / formatting code.

Comment: I just edited my question.:))

Comment: @Battlelamb there we go - `Convert.ToDecimal` is a locale-dependent conversion and most likely is the cause of everything; consider specifying an explicit `CultureInfo` in that call